# Laravel 5.3 admin guard not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to login from two different model using same login form. I have defined admin guard in config/Auth.php. But when I define admin guard in Foundation/AuthenticateUsers it checks the database table to validate the user but redirects back to same login form.

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

Foundation/AuthenticatUsers

```
protected function guard()
   {
       return Auth::guard('admin');
   }
public function login(Request $request)
  {
   $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, $request-    >has('remember'))) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
    elseif(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to include some code so people can see the problem

Comment: hi @AndyHolmes .. i have updated the question.. can you help?

Comment: You have a typo here `return Auth::guard('admin);` FYI

Comment: Yes i corrected it but its still not working, the web guard allows the user to dashboard.. but the admin guard checks the table but redirects back to login page

Answer (score 0):

Admin guard redirects to login page because of middleware auth, i think you need to do something like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}
```

Read this [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#protecting-routes), part "Specifying A Guard"