# How do I allow a user to create new users and allow login in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am developing a app in Laravel 5.3 where multiple users can login and create new users but restriction in view. The app will also have a main admin who will control overall app. Example:

1. Admin
2. User

   2.1 Child User 1

   2.2 Child User 2

Answer (score 1):

To create roles and permission. You must refer to [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) which is a well-known package which I find suitable for this task

Answer (score 1):

> you can do this like super admin can create user if he wants like

```
 public function postCompanyRegistrationByAdmin (Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
        'company_name' => 'required',
        'company_phone_no' => 'required',
        'company_address' => 'required',
        'company_city' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
    ]);
    $company = new Company;
    $company->id = $user->id;
    $company->name = $request->get("company_name");
    $company->phone_no = $request->get("company_phone_no");
    $company->address =$request->get("company_address");
    $company->city = $request->get("company_city");
    $company->company_logo = $request->get("company_logo");
    $company->country = $request->get("country");
    $company->save();
    $message = 'Company successfully Registered.';
    return redirect()->route('Companies')->with(['message' => $message]);
}
```

> its route will be in middle where admin like

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'ShoesPlanner', 'middleware' => 'Admin'), function() {
    Route::post('companyRegistrationByAdmin', array('as' => 'companyRegistrationByAdmin', 'uses' => 'SuperAdminController@postCompanyRegistrationByAdmin'));
```

});

> Middleware will like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->user_type == 'Admin') {

        return $next ($request);


    }
            return redirect()->route('login');

}
```

Comment: I have defined a guard to allow login to the child users.. but the guard doesn't seem to be working.. would you mind checking this previous question that I asked earlier. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279712/laravel-5-3-admin-guard-not-working)

Comment: You can use my approach for your work. I does not understand your previous question. You can do login of different users by defining a flag